# How to ReportProgress multiple values?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to send an array in a single DoWork, but in ReportProgress, there is no way to receive an array, I'm not sure what should I do to be able to pass a array, really appreciate if anyone has any idea.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
public void backgroundWorkerXY_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            X = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1);
            Y = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1) + 5;
            backgroundWorkerX.ReportProgress(X,Y); // pass X and Y

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        } while (true);
    }
```

Then here to pass these two values to change the locations of a image:

```
    public void backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged(object sender, object sender1, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point((int.Parse(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString())), (int.Parse(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString())) );
    // Not sure how to let a single ProgressChanged to send two values here
    }
```

There is an alternative way to do it is to separate them, for example, pass X, and pass Y, but to change a location of image, the values must be a Point contains 2 values (what I discovered so far, may not be correct), so I am assuming it has to be in a single ProgressChanged,

This is what I also tried

```
pictureBox1.Location.X = new Point((int.Parse(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString())));
```

However it said 
"CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of 'Control.Location' because it is not a variable"

What I am trying to do is to change the location for both X and Y, I am really welcome to any alternative solutions, really appreciate any ideas or thoughts!

Comment: is there a reason for not setting the location of the image right away?

Comment: @Niklas Probably because calling UI methods from a background thread is not allowed.

Comment: looks like he is trying to achieve some animation/ moving the images on screen.

Comment: you can do that by  using invokations, like `Control.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{//move image here}));` where control would be your control, i.e Form. that makes the ui thread move the image for you without errors. it not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a project to do positioning, I'm pretty good on hardware and python side, but need to do GUI on C#, this is really a challenge for no experience in GUI programming, still trying to learn

Comment: @tedhan is okie, we are all here to learn and improve each other, no one is going to judge you here.

Comment: @Vignesh.N thanks!!! You helped yesterday and gave me a lot of ideas, I think I'm on the right track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts second argument as `object`. You can use that to either return a custom datatype or simply use [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public void backgroundWorkerXY_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        X = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1);
        Y = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1) + 5;
        backgroundWorkerX.ReportProgress(50, new Tuple<int, int>(X,Y));

        Thread.Sleep(50);
    } while (true);
}
```

[`UserState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) will be passed to `ProgressChanged` event args

```
public void backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var args = (Tuple<int, int>)e.UserState;
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(args.Item1, args.Item2) );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but getting "CS0123 No overload for 'backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged' matches delegate 'ProgressChangedEventHandler'", I think it is because of a new "object sender1",

Comment: In my main form, I wrote this:

Comment: backgroundWorkerXY.DoWork += backgroundWorkerXY_DoWork;
            backgroundWorkerXY.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorkerXY.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorkerXY.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: I may need to modify this?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! THANKS A LOT!!! Thank you guys so much for spending time help me, I'm now working all the methods you provide, trying to learn

Answer (score 2):

the `ReportProgress` has an overload which accepts any object, you can use that.

```
worker.ReportProgress( someProgressPercentage, new Point(x,y));

private void  backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = (Point)e.UserState;
    pictureBox1.Location = point;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried @Adnan Umer's method and it works!!! The image is moving right now!!! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a custom class, like e.g.

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

Then use it similar to this:

```
public void backgroundWorkerXY_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        backgroundWorkerX.ReportProgress(
            0,
            new MyCustomClass 
            {
                X = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1),
                Y = -(RSSI_PI1_ST1) + 5
            } );

        Thread.Sleep(50);
    } while (true);
}
```

And consume it like:

```
public void backgroundWorkerXY_ProgressChanged(
    object sender, 
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var my = (MyCustomClass)e.UserState;

    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(my.X, my.Y);
}
```

Some references:

- [MSDN documentation of the `ReportProgress` method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN documentation of the `ProgressChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I actually found this method in another post, but I'm getting an error saying "CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WindowsFormsApplication10.Form1.MyCustomClass' to 'int'", I think it's because backgroundWorkerX.ReportProgress() can only pass integer, is this correct?

Comment: @tedhan Sorry, wrong signature, I've added the missing `0,` in my code above.

Comment: No need to sorry, I actually appreciate a lot for your help, I've successfully get it work, and thanks a lot!!!

Comment: just a suggestion, you should avoid creating custom classes and use in-built classes for well known things like `Point`, `Size` etc.